# How to force an element in front of others?

Tags: css, z-index

I have a web page where I can inject an element using a hook. Due to the hook mechanism, I cannot influence the place where the element is injected and I cannot influence the style or class attributes of the existing elements. However, I can influence the attributes of the element I inject.

My problem: I want the injected element to be highest in the z-order. I (1) assigned the element a `position:fixed`, (2) provided top and left and (3) a high z-index value, and (4) there is no transform used and the parent has no z-index. However, the element nevertheless is partially covered by other elements which (5) have no z-index set and are (6) position fixed with (7) set top and left.

What am I doing wrong - and how can I fix that given that I can only provide my injected element with attributes?

**Added:** Looks like I somehow failed to point out that I *did* RTFM, read the docs and the spec, and *did* Google for a number of "how to" pages before asking here. And, yes, the minimal examples also work out for me as the tutorials say. My hope actually was (and still is) to discover some new, yet missing aspect, because after a day I did not, thus far, find some. There is RTFM. There also is RTFQ. :-)

**More:** The element I want to move in front is an `<embed>` and in a second attempt an `<iframe>`. I cannot and should not modify the document sequence nor the z-index of parents, since this would destroy the existing document flow and would not be compatible with the hook mechanism of the page generator. I simply want a kind of "modal" or "covering all" element in front of the remaining page, whatever it is.

Comment: Here is a page that can shed some light on why z-index doesn't work. https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/ 1. parent got a z-index, 2 element must have a non-static position (or flex), 3) it's `transformed`,

Comment: Thanx. This is a good page, indeed, and it was one of the first I checked. And, no, none of the 3 conditions apply. So what's next...

Comment: What's next is to provide code, because it's impossible to draw any conclusions from what you wrote, hence why other people downvoted this thread.

Comment: Yes! Of course! Problem is: In all smaller examples the code works as expected; the offending page is a large, complex page including so much minified external css and js that I can't reasonably expect anyone to look at it. Could also be the build/ minification process which breaks some css part? Anyhow, I solve the orig. problem now by injecting in the hook some javascript which dynamically adds the element at the end of the document. Not elegant but it solves my case. Sometimes one has to live with such stuff - and with downvotes. as well. Appreciate you sugg.

Answer (score -1):

It's essentially placing an element, behind or in front of another element.
`z-index: -1;` behind content, `z-index: 1;` in front of.

Per [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

> -The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

> -An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

> -**Note**: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and flex items (elements that are direct children of display:flex elements).

**Note**: If two positioned elements overlap without a z-index specified, the element positioned last in the HTML code will be shown on top. Also, stacking context and and 3D transformations could potentially cause strange behavior when using `z-index`.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* z-index notes */
z-index:9999;     /* top most layer*/
z-index:1;        /* 1st layer above default */
z-index:0;        /* default layers */
z-index:-9999;   /* bottom last layer*/
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu</p>
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/527cbf/fff">
```

Comment: z-index is unreliable, so this is not a good answer. stacking contexts and 3d transforms can make z-index values useless.

Comment: @JohnMiller that doesn’t make much sense. `Z-index` is not unreliable… why would it exist if it was? “Stacking contexts” as you say is literally the definition of `z-index`. & I think everyone knows that `z-index` is two-dimensional. Good thing this question doesn’t say anything about that.

Comment: @JohnMiller sorry this doesn't satisfy what you were looking for with your search query. May need to write a better question in google.

Comment: @Kameron people turning to SO for answers likely have already tried all of the obvious things like setting the z-index. Instead, they are probably getting screwed over by unexpected behavior/quirk of css. Stacking context and transformZ can definitely cause strange behavior, and so it should arguably be mentioned in the answer. I'm sorry that I downvoted you, but this is my honest opinion.

Comment: Also, I stand my ground about how stacking context makes z-index extremely unreliable. CSS is a language designed to make it impossible to not have the following scenario: two piece of code with distant colocation strongly coupling/interleaving together. This describes stacking context in a nutshell. It was a mistake. This ia ABYSMAL language design. It's like the first that gets taught in any software design course. And yet us web devs are stuck with it.

Comment: @JohnMiller Added the warning about stacking context and 3D transformations to my answer. Please revise.